# How can I efficiently stack two sections of a dataframe on top of each other with different column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

## Question:

How can I take a dataframe that contains paired data (but different column names) and efficiently combine it? (solution does not need to be `tidyverse`).

### Starting Dataframe:

I have origin/destination pair information in a dataframe like this...

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(orig_city = c("Philadelphia", "Orlando", "Los Angeles"),
          orig_state = c("PA", "FL", "CA"),
          orig_zip = c("21948", "48321", "98765"),
          dest_city = c("Boston", "St Louis", "Houston"),
          dest_state = c("MA", "MO", "TX"),
          dest_zip = c("12345", "67890", "45678"))
```

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  orig_city    orig_state orig_zip dest_city dest_state dest_zip
  <chr>        <chr>      <chr>    <chr>     <chr>      <chr>   
1 Philadelphia PA         21948    Boston    MA         12345   
2 Orlando      FL         48321    St Louis  MO         67890   
3 Los Angeles  CA         98765    Houston   TX         45678
```

...and I need to get geo-location data for each city, but that information doesn't depend on whether it is origin or destination, so I want to stack it and process in one set of columns.  Here's one method to solve my problem with the correct output:

### Desired Dataframe

```
df_stacked1 <- tibble(city = c(df$orig_city, df$dest_city),
                     state = c(df$orig_state, df$dest_state),
                     zip = c(df$orig_zip, df$dest_zip))
```

```
> df_stacked1
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  city         state zip  
  <chr>        <chr> <chr>
1 Philadelphia PA    21948
2 Orlando      FL    48321
3 Los Angeles  CA    98765
4 Boston       MA    12345
5 St Louis     MO    67890
6 Houston      TX    45678
```

While that works, it doesn't scale well if I have say... 15 pairs instead of 3.

I have another solution using `rbind()`, but that requires that the names match, and while it would scale better, I am wondering if there's a better way still that I haven't found.

### Alternate working solution

```
df_orig <- df[, 1:3]
colnames(df_orig) <- gsub("orig_", "", colnames(df_orig))
df_dest <- df[, 4:6]  
colnames(df_dest) <- gsub("dest_", "", colnames(df_dest))
df_stacked2 <- rbind(df_orig, df_dest)
```

```
> df_stacked2
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  city         state zip  
  <chr>        <chr> <chr>
1 Philadelphia PA    21948
2 Orlando      FL    48321
3 Los Angeles  CA    98765
4 Boston       MA    12345
5 St Louis     MO    67890
6 Houston      TX    45678
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(),  
                      names_to = c("set", ".value"), 
                      names_sep = "_",
                      cols_vary = "slowest")

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  set   city         state zip  
  <chr> <chr>        <chr> <chr>
1 orig  Philadelphia PA    21948
2 orig  Orlando      FL    48321
3 orig  Los Angeles  CA    98765
4 dest  Boston       MA    12345
5 dest  St Louis     MO    67890
6 dest  Houston      TX    4567
```

Comment: Seems op want columnwise arrangement rather than rowwise. better use `names_vary = 'slowest'`. Also seems OP is not interested in the `set` column. I would use `names_to  = c(NA, '.value')`

Comment: I presume you mean `cols_vary = "slowest"`? Good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @Onyambu, I did not ask for the `set` column, but I'm okay with it.  The order wasn't important to me, either.  I actually have to run `unique()` anyway, since in the real dataset I have duplicates, and I want to minimize hitting the API for geocode.  But I never looked at `cols_vary` parameter before, so good help here from @JonSpring.

Comment: yes yes, `cols_vary` for `pivot_longer` and `names_vary` for `pivot_wider`. i mixed the two. Sorry about that